# application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler) is not called before user taps on notification

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

I saw in several places:

1. https://www.raywenderlich.com/11395893-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started

> If your app was running either in the foreground or the background, the system notifies your app by calling application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:). When the user opens the app by tapping the push notification, iOS may call this method again, so you can update the UI and display relevant information.

2. https://medium.com/fenrir-inc/handling-ios-push-notifications-the-not-so-apparent-side-420891ddf10b

> Background: When the notification arrives. + If the user taps the
> notification, before the app enters foreground.

that if I set `"content-available": 1` and add some data payload to notification, the method `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler)` will be called twice (unless I set delegate for `UNUserNotificationCenter`) when my app is in background and then when user taps on notification.

Unfortunately, I didn't notice such behavior, the method above was only called once after user taps on notification.

The notification I'm trying to send is something like:

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "Test",
    "sound": "default",
    "content-available": 1
  },
  "test": "abc"
}
```

Has something changed in iOS 13/14 (the Ray Wenderlich tutorial seems to be up-to-date) or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

Interestingly, after reinstalling the app multiple times, it started working. I set the UNNotificationCenterdelegate and it works like that:

1. App is in background, the server sends notification with `content-available: 1`.
2. System shows alert and `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` is called so I can fetch new data.
3. User taps on alert, `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` is called, so I can navigate to particular view.

Is it a proper way of handling push notifications with data payload?

Comment: are you using the UNNotificationCentre delegate that was introduced in iOS 10?

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not setting the delegate for UNNotificationCenter, as I want to be notified before user taps on notification.